# Find a midpoint between two points

Tags: c++

How do i calculate a midpoint between point a and b? Will my code gonna work?

```
struct Point
{
  int x;
  int y;    
};

Point midpoint(const Point& a, const Point& b)
{
    double middle = (a.x + b.x) / 2;
    return middle;
}
```

Comment: you're missing the Y dimension, and mixing your return types. So, no, it won't work.

Comment: I suggest you step away from the computer and figure out how to do this by hand first.

Comment: And the Z dimension.Are we also using temporal dimensions?

Comment: "Will my code gonna work?"  To answer this, try running the code on your computer and see what happens.

Answer (score 13):

This should work:

```
Point midpoint(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    Point ret;
    ret.x = (a.x + b.x) / 2;
    ret.y = (a.y + b.y) / 2;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This contains UB in case `a.x + b.x` or `a.y + b.y` overflows in either direction.

Answer (score 5):

If midpoint returns a Point, why are you returning a double?

Comment: Fair point (pun intended) but this should really be a comment (I know you don't have the rep for that yet, but still).

Answer (score 5):

You need to return

```
Point p;
p.x = (a.x+b.x)/2;
p.y = (a.y+b.y)/2;
return p;
```

Comment: this can be shortened to `return { (a.x + b.x) / 2, (a.y + b.y) / 2 };`

Comment: @Borgleader. As far as I know it cannot, because the returned struct would not have the `x` and `y` data members.

Comment: @Kavka: The function _must_ return a `Point`, and `Point` has `x` and `y` members. No need to worry about that, whatsoever! It's far more exciting (and surprising, if you haven't seen this feature before), that C++11 takes the initialisation list @Borgleader wrote and constructs a `Point` from it for you.

Comment: @Kavka Contains UB. for a.x + b.x > INT_MAX or < INT_MIN, same for y.  Also yes, it can be shortened to that.

Answer (score 3):

```
Point midpoint(const Point& a, const Point& b)
{
    //double middle = (a.x + b.x) / 2;
    //return middle;
    Point middle;
    middle.x = (a.x + b.x) / 2;
    middle.y = (a.y + b.y) / 2;
    return middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::midpoint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/midpoint) introduced in c++20, which guarantees no UB for integer types and at most one inexact operation for floating point types.
The other answers suggesting `(a.x + b.x) / 2` contain undefined behavior for signed integer members in `Point`. This is because signed integer overflow is undefined. This occurs when `a.x + b.x` is larger than INT_MAX or smaller than INT_MIN (in case they are both negative numbers). The same logic applies to `a.y + b.y`.

```cpp
#include <numeric>
// [...]
Point midpoint(const Point& pointA, const Point& pointB)
{
  return Point{
    std::midpoint(pointA.x, pointB.x),
    std::midpoint(pointA.y, pointB.y)
  };
}
```

Assuming you have a constructor for Point that takes two arguments for x and y. This will also work for the struct provided by OP.

This will round the integers towards the first point. If mathematical rounding is desired, cast the arguments to float first.

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>
// [...]
Point midpoint(const Point& pointA, const Point& pointB)
{
  return Point{
    static_cast<int>(
      std::round(std::midpoint(
        static_cast<float>(pointA.x), static_cast<float>(pointB.x)
      ))
    ),
    static_cast<int>(
      std::round(std::midpoint(
        static_cast<float>(pointA.y), static_cast<float>(pointB.y)
      ))
    )
  };
}
```

You could also use linear interpolation with [`std::lerp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lerp) instead, which is less verbose since it implicitly casts the arguments into floating point values.

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>
// [...]
Point midpoint(const Point& pointA, const Point& pointB)
{
  return Point{
    static_cast<int>(std::round(std::lerp(pointA.x, pointB.x, 0.5F))),
    static_cast<int>(std::round(std::lerp(pointA.y, pointB.y, 0.5F)))
  };
}
```